# List out of range error in python code

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, outofrangeexception

I am writing a simple python program which allows us to list all video files in a directory and play them according to the user input. However, I am getting an list out of range error while running this code.

Code:

```
import os

from subprocess import Popen

def processFile(currentDir):
    # Get the absolute path of the currentDir parameter
    currentDir = os.path.abspath(currentDir)                                         
    global list
    list=[]

    filesInCurDir = os.listdir(currentDir)

    # Traverse through all files
    for file in filesInCurDir:
        curFile = os.path.join(currentDir, file)

        # Check if it's a normal file or directory
        if os.path.isfile(curFile):
            # Get the file extension
            curFileExtension = curFile[-3:]

            # Check if the file has an extension of typical video files
            if curFileExtension in ['avi', 'dat', 'mp4', 'mkv', 'vob']:
                # We have got a video file! Increment the counter
                processFile.counter += 1
                list.append('curFile')

                # Print it's name
                print(processFile.counter,  file)
        else:
            # We got a directory, enter into it for further processing
            processFile(curFile)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get the current working directory
    currentDir = os.getcwd()

    print('Starting processing in %s' % currentDir)

    # Set the number of processed files equal to zero
    processFile.counter = 0

    # Start Processing
    processFile(currentDir)

    # We are done. Exit now.
    print('\n -- %s Movie File(s) found in directory %s --' \
          % (processFile.counter, currentDir))
    print('Enter the file you want to play')
    x = int(input())
    path = list[x-1]
    oxmp=Popen(['omxplayer',path])
```

Comment: What line do you get the out of range error on?

Comment: @Crummy: It looks like the likely line for them to be getting the error is the second-to-last line - it's the only line with a non-slice list index. The issue is probably related to entering a number not in the range 1 ... processFile.counter in response to the input prompt.

Comment: `list` is a reserved word in Python, you can of course use it a variable name, but you mask the use of the built-in

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide the full traceback.

Comment: Yes i get the error in second last line of the code even when input is 2

Comment: Anybody with a solution or explanation,please help

Answer (score 1):

Aha, found your problem.

In `processFile`, you say

```
def processFile(currentDir):
    # ...
    global list
    list=[]
    # ...
    processFile(...)
```

This means that, whenever you recurse, you are clearing the list again! This means that the `processFile.counter` number becomes out-of-sync with the actual length of list.

Three notes on this:

- Storing variables on a function like `processFile.counter` is generally frowned upon, AFAIK.
- There's no need for a separate counter; you can simply put `len(list)` to find the number of entries in your list.
- To fix the list problem itself, consider initializing the list variable outside of the function or passing it in as a parameter to be modified.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, perhaps accept it?